# Explanation about resample_partition in R

Tags: linear-model

I hope this is the correct place to ask:

I am trying to learn linear regression. When I read about linear regression with R, and I found resample_partition function in modelr.

Here are my questions:

1. What is the benefit of partitioning in general? Whats the difference if I don't partition my data into training, validation, and testing set?
2. My understanding is we use resample_partition when we try to model large data and want to save memory (please correct me if I am wrong). If I just have small dataset, would it make sense to use resample_partition?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll answer because I don't have enough points to comment.

1. The benefit to partitioning.  When people fit models, the goal is not to fit a model to the data you have, it is to fit a model to the data you don't have.  So, if you create a partition, one called train and the other called test, you can fit the model on the train data set.  After that you should ask yourself.  How does this model work on the data I don't have?  Because you have your test partition, you can test your model on that partition.  So in this case, the test partition represents the data you don't have.  Obviously you do have it, but because you haven't used it yet, it is still untainted by your model fitting activities.
2. `modelr::resample_partition` creates a pointer (index) to rows in your data instead of replicating your actual data.  The pointers take up less space than creating a copy called test and train.  In that way, it is useful if your data set is to large to justify making and extra copy of it.  When you use `modelr::crossv_kfold` the advantage is even greater.

References:

- https://github.com/tidyverse/modelr
- https://drsimonj.svbtle.com/k-fold-cross-validation-with-modelr-and-broom
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nZAM5OXrktY

Comment: +1 This is a good answer and should not have been a comment.